# (C++) How do i read all files of a directory and put their contents in a vector/std::list?

Tags: c++, file, vector, getline

The contents of the files are line by line and go in a "Schedule" struct. My objective is to stock these schedules in .txt files so they don't disappear after the end of execution, and to stock the structs in a vector or a list when i execute it again, by reading all files of a separated folder.
I have no idea how to do this.

I supposed i could use getline() for a folder but even if it worked it would probably just give me the file names. That could work in a way, but getline() doesn't work like that.

Comment: [`std::filesystem::directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator)

Comment: Ted's answer is spot on, in general everything related to file/folder managment can be found in  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem. cppreference is a good site to know about since you can find all C++ and standard library info there (including examples).

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [`std::filesystem::directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator).

But first things first. The first thing you could do is to define an `operator>>` to read *one* `Schedule` from an `std::istream` (like a `std::ifstream`).

```cpp
#include <istream>

class Schedule {
private:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Schedule& s) {
        // extract _one_ Schedule from the istream:
        return is >> s.a >> s.b >> s.c;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Schedule& s) {
        return os << s.a << ' ' << s.b << ' ' << s.c << '\n';
    }

    // whatever is stored in a Schedule:
    int a, b, c;
};
```

... and in your container containing all the schedules you take two iterators and/or a range in order to populate it:

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

class Schedules {
public:
    // populating via iterators
    template<class It, class EndIt>
    Schedules(It begin, EndIt end) : schedules(begin, end) {}

    // or via a range:
    Schedules(std::ranges::input_range auto&& range) :
        Schedules(std::ranges::begin(range), std::ranges::end(range)) {}

    auto begin() { return schedules.begin(); }
    auto end() { return schedules.end(); }

private:
    std::vector<Schedule> schedules;
};
```

With those in place, you can create a class to open a file and provide iterators to populate your `Schedules` container. It can be a rather thin wrapper around a `std::ifstream` with the `begin()` and `end()` iterator type being [`std::istream_iterator<Schedule>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator()) which can then be used to populate the `Schedules` container.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

class ScheduleFileLoader {
public:
    ScheduleFileLoader() = default;

    ScheduleFileLoader(const std::filesystem::path& path) : ifs(path) {}

    ScheduleFileLoader(const std::filesystem::directory_entry& dent) :
        ScheduleFileLoader(dent.path()) {}

    operator bool() const { return ifs.good(); }

    void open(const std::filesystem::path& path) {
        if(ifs.is_open()) ifs.close();
        ifs.open(path);
    }

    void open(const std::filesystem::directory_entry& dent) {
        open(dent.path());
    }

    using iterator = std::istream_iterator<Schedule>;

    iterator begin() { return iterator{ifs}; }
    iterator end() { return iterator{}; }

private:
    std::ifstream ifs{};
};
```

and you could use it to load the schedules from one file:

```cpp
Schedules schedules(ScheduleFileLoader("data_directory/schedules01.txt"));
```

But you want to take it further by loading *all* files in a directory into your `Schedules` container. You need to

- Iterate over all the files in the directory where the files containing `Schedule`s are stored.
- Open each file using a `ScheduleFileLoader`
- Provide iterators to treat the stream of `Schedule`s as one range.

You can then encapsulate `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` and a `ScheduleFileLoader` in yet another class, `ScheduleDirectoryLoader`. When its `ScheduleFileLoader` has depleated a file, open the next file - and keep going until the `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` reaches the end of the directory. This requires a custom iterator.

```cpp
#include <filesystem>

class ScheduleDirectoryLoader {
public:
    ScheduleDirectoryLoader(const std::filesystem::path& dir) : m_dir(dir) {}
    ScheduleDirectoryLoader(const std::filesystem::directory_entry& dent) :
        ScheduleDirectoryLoader(dent.path()) {}

    struct iterator {                         // the custom iterator
        using difference_type = std::intptr_t;
        using value_type = Schedule;
        using pointer = value_type*;
        using reference = value_type&;
        using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;

        iterator() = default; // end iterator

        iterator(const iterator& other) : dit(other.dit), fit(other.fit) {}
        iterator(iterator&&) = default;
        iterator& operator=(const iterator& other) {
            dit = other.dit;
            // the ScheduleFileLoader is not copyable because ifstream is not
            fit = other.fit;
            return *this;
        }
        iterator& operator=(iterator&&) = default;

        iterator(const std::filesystem::path& dir) : dit(dir) {
            if(dit != std::filesystem::directory_iterator{}) {
                sfl.open(*dit);
                if(sfl) fit = sfl.begin();
            }
        }

        const Schedule& operator*() const { return *fit; }

        // The advancement of this iterator:
        // 1. step the ScheduleFileLoader::iterator
        // 2. if it reaches the end of the file, ...
        // 3. step the directory iterator
        // 4. if it doesn't reach the end of the directory, ...
        // 5. open the new file
        // 6. if opening the file succeeds, get a new begin() iterator
        iterator& operator++() {
            if(++fit == ScheduleFileLoader::iterator{}) { // end of this file
                if(++dit != std::filesystem::directory_iterator{}) {
                    // not last in directory
                    sfl.open(*dit);
                    if(sfl) fit = sfl.begin();
                }
            }
            return *this;
        }
        iterator operator++(int) {
            iterator copy(*this);
            ++(*this);
            return copy;
        }

        bool operator==(const iterator& rhs) const { return fit == rhs.fit; }
        bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); }

    private:
        std::filesystem::directory_iterator dit{};
        ScheduleFileLoader sfl;
        ScheduleFileLoader::iterator fit;
    };

    iterator begin() { return m_dir; }
    iterator end() { return {}; }

private:
    std::filesystem::path m_dir;
};
```

With the `ScheduleFileLoader` and `ScheduleDirectoryLoader` in place, you can load a single file or all the files. If you need to be able to load from other sources than files, you create another adapter that provides iterators that dereferences into something that can be used to construct a `Schedule` (like a `std::istream_iterator<Schedule>`). It's sometimes as easy as with the single source `ScheduleFileLoader` and sometimes a bit more tricky as with the `ScheduleDirectoryLoader`.

Usage example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Schedules schedules(ScheduleDirectoryLoader("data_directory"));

    for(const Schedule& s : schedules) {
        std::cout << s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ted it is functionally a good example.  However from a desing point of view  I think this should not be the Schedule class itself but more a schedule loader/factory. I tend to keep file/io seperate from classes (last year its files, today databases, tomorrow it is internet streams). I also am aware I digress from the initial question by OP ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes, you are probably right. I'm afraid it may bloat the answer and obscure the interesting parts a bit though. Perhaps not...

Comment: @PepijnKramer I noticed that there now is a simpler answer that covers the base case so I went nuts and wrote some adapters. :)

Comment: I didn't want to throw a whole lot of work at you. And you where probably right that more code would obfuscate the answer. But I love this thorough example, there is a lot in here a lot of people can learn from :)  (Few places where I would add `final` or `noexcept`) but that would be nitpicking ;)

Comment: To OP : the reason for using stream overloads it that there are many source of infromation that already provide streams or you can create your own streams for.

Answer (score 1):

The same as @Ted above.

But we can simplify a bit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    namespace fs = std::filesystem;
    std::vector<fs::directory_entry> dirents{fs::directory_iterator("."), fs::directory_iterator{}};

    for (auto const& dir: dirents) {
        std::cout << dir.path() << "\n";
    }
}
```